# PySpark : Add column with goup index

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm really new to spark and have little trouble

Suppose I have this :

```
'a' | 'b' 
0   | 5416 
1   | 5278 
2   | 2    
3   | 568  
0   | 416  
1   | 216  
2   | 56   
3   | 56
```

and I want a third column with a kind of index that group by de series of 'a' like this :

```
'a' | 'b'  | 'Index'
0   | 5416 | 1
1   | 5278 | 1
2   | 2    | 1 
3   | 568  | 1 
0   | 416  | 2
1   | 216  | 2
2   | 56   | 2
3   | 56   | 2
```

How can I do thi ? with Window() ?
Thanks !

Comment: What is the logic ?

Comment: I made a mistajke sorry, corrected